# Gulp Refresh Wordpress PHP files

Tags: php, wordpress, gulp

I have a basic gulp.js setup running in my wordpress environment. Everything works how I would like except for the way I am reloading my changed .php files. When gulp finishes running the task it seems to be loading the task twice meaning that it will start-finish the task then re-run the task again. The files I had gulp watching are located in the root directory as well as the library directory. Also, is there a way to have gulp only look for changed files. I have it set up like this:

```
// PHP TASK
gulp.task(‘php’, function () {
watch({glob:['.php','library/.php']})
.pipe(plugins.livereload(server))
.pipe(plugins.notify({ message: ‘PHP task complete’ }));
});

// Watch
gulp.task(‘watch’, function() {

// Listen on port 35729
server.listen(35729, function (err) {
if (err) {
return console.log(err)
};

// Watch php files
gulp.watch(['php']);
});

});

// Default task
gulp.task(‘default’, ['php', 'watch']);
```

====================================

Here is the result from a single save.

```
[gulp] index.php was reloaded.
… Reload /Users/jfearing/Sites/zurb/wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS-master/index.php …
… Reload /Users/jfearing/Sites/zurb/wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS-master/index.php …
… Reload /Users/jfearing/Sites/zurb/wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS-master/index.php …
… Reload /Users/jfearing/Sites/zurb/wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS-master/index.php …
[gulp] index.php was reloaded.
… Reload /Users/jfearing/Sites/zurb/wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS-master/index.php …
… Reload /Users/jfearing/Sites/zurb/wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS-master/index.php …
… Reload /Users/jfearing/Sites/zurb/wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS-master/index.php …
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

> ```
> // Default task
> gulp.task(‘default’, ['php', 'watch']);
> ```

you could try this:

```
// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['php'], function() {
  gulp.start('watch');
});
```

But I can't test it out, at the moment.

Full snippet:

```
'use strict';
/* global gulp, watch, plugins, server, console */

// PHP TASK
gulp.task('php', function () {
  watch({
    glob:['.php','library/.php']
  }).pipe(plugins.livereload(server))
  .pipe(plugins.notify({ message: 'PHP task complete' }));
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {

  // Listen on port 35729
  server.listen(35729, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }

    // Watch php files
    gulp.watch(['php']);
  });

});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['php'], function() {
  gulp.start('watch');
});
```

If this snippet should not work, or the save times keeps higher than one, try to edit this one:

```
gulp.task('php', function () {
  watch({
    glob:['.php','library/.php']
  }) ...
```

Best regards.

*Note:
The first two lines in the full snippet are just for jshint, so I can proof the code, while I can't execute it without a local located php-library.*